# What is the use of "actions/checkout" in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions

I saw a lot of uses of :

```
jobs:
  myjob:
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: "actions/checkout@something"
      - ...
```

But i can not find what is the purpose of the line :

```
uses : "actions/checkout@something"
```

Is it similar to this ?

```
 run: git checkout something
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For this line: `uses : "actions/checkout@something"`, it will use the `actions/checkout` github action (source [here](https://github.com/actions/checkout))  with the ref `something`. This ref only refers to the github action version (nothing to do with your repo)

The `uses` statement refers to a github action that is being used in this step. From [github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses) for `jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].uses`:

> Selects an action to run as part of a step
> in your job. An action is a reusable unit of code. You can use an
> action defined in the same repository as the workflow, a public
> repository, or in a published Docker container image.

From [actions/checkout readme](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-v2) :

> This action checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your workflow can access it.

By default it checks out only one commit. My understanding is that it's doing something similar to:

```
git fetch --depth 1 origin $GITHUB_REF
```

This action also persists an auth token in git config. This way, your workflow can run authenticated git commands

By default, it clones your current repository (`{{ github.repository }}`) but you can also use this action to clone a different repository, and specify additionnal parameters like `token`, `branch`, `path` etc...

An example with additionnal input parameters: check out all git history by setting `fetch-depth` to `0` (default is `1`), see [usage doc](https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage):

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```

Comment: *"This action checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE,"* What does this mean? I thought you could only checkout a branch not a repository.

Comment: Why name the action as `checkout` when its actually running `git fetch` command?

Answer (score 12):

Understanding terminologies made things clearer

- *Remote repo* - It can also be referred to as the origin
- *Origin* - the default name of the remote repo or the source repo being cloned
- *Head* - a reference to human-friendly names for branches
- *git checkout* - switch to a particular branch and displaying the changes currently on that branch
- *origin/name_of_branch* - branch name created when fetching changes from a particular branch on the remote repo

**Side Note:** When git fetch is used, a custom branch is created locally in the form "origin/name_of_branch", changes on this branch can be viewed locally. These changes are the updated version of the files, not the specific change in that file as seen when commits are being inspected on GitHub.

Back to the question
When the action is executed

```
jobs:
  myjob:
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: "actions/checkout@something"
      - ...
```

The default steps being executed are:

1. The current repo in which the workflow is being triggered gets cloned.
2. Depending on the defined events such as a push or pull request:

- For a push event, it runs the command below, where $GITHUB_REF points to the latest commit on the specified branch for the push event in the workflow.

```
git fetch --depth 1 $GITHUB_REF
```

- For pull requests, it checks $GITHUB_REF points to the latest commit on the pull request source branch. This means it points to the would-be code/result from merging the pull request. This is the code/result other steps within the job are executed on such as running builds or tests. (Not completely sure of the command which runs under the hood)

Environment variables being referenced in the commands are explained [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables).
Additional options can be added to implement specific processes or scenarios such as checking out a different branch. This can be found in the [official repo readme](https://github.com/actions/checkout).

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to perform a `git fetch` after cloning the repository (the case of push event)?