# github actions not getting the current git fetch value

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions, versioning

I manage my automatic release and deployment processes with Github actions.

In my yml file, things increase by npm version and according to the label in the pull request, respectively. Make a new commit and do the deployment process and complete the actions.

My problem here is my version number in the development branch, for example, I am updating the 1.2.3 patch version. It becomes 1.2.4 and reflects on the development branch, but when deploying, it sends version 1.2.3. How can i solve this problem.

An example from my yml file

```
name: development deploy

on:
    pull_request:
        types:
            - closed
        branches:
            - development
    push:
        branches:
            - development

jobs:
    automatic-version-update:
        name: Automatic version update
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
        steps:
            - name: Check Out Repository
              uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - name: Setup Node.js
              uses: actions/setup-node@v2
              with:
                  node-version: '16.15'
            - name: Update Version
              run: |
                  git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
                  git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
                  PR_LABELS=$(jq --raw-output '.pull_request.labels[].name' $GITHUB_EVENT_PATH)

                  if [[ $PR_LABELS == *"minor version"* ]]; then
                    npm version minor -m "Updated to minor version %s"

                  elif [[ $PR_LABELS == *"major version"* ]]; then
                    npm version major -m "Updated to major version %s"

                  elif [[ $PR_LABELS == *"patch version"* ]]; then
                    npm version patch -m "Updated to patch version %s"
                  fi

            - name: Push Changes
              uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
              with:
                  github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
                  branch: ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}
    build-deploy:
        needs: automatic-version-update
        name: Deployment jobs
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Check Out Repository
              uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - name: Install Node.js
              uses: actions/setup-node@v1
              with:
                  node-version: '16.15'
            - name: Install packages
              run: yarn install
            - name: React build
              run: yarn run build:dev
            - name: Deploy to Server
              uses: easingthemes/ssh-deploy@main
              env:
                  SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
                  SOURCE: '.'
                  REMOTE_HOST: ${{ secrets.SERVER_HOST }}
                  REMOTE_USER: ${{ secrets.SERVER_USERNAME }}
                  TARGET: ${{ secrets.SERVER_ROOT_FOLDER }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TLDR; Checkout the correct branch.
>
> Microsoft Github Actions just adds a couple layers of abstractions around `git(1)`. When something unexpected happens, double-check the **real** `git(1)` workflow is clear (e.g. works locally), then verify the Microsoft Github Action Workflow uses the correct actions with the correct configuration step by step.

---

Thank you for sharing your question, you asked:

> When deploying, it sends version 1.2.3. How can i [sic!] solve this problem. [sic!]

The solution may not be directly visible, so let's uncover what happens here first.

The commit you're creating is in the git repository at the `HEAD` commanded per [`uses: actions/checkout@v3`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) (Cf. [GitHub - jobs : what is : use actions/checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67131269/367456). IIRC in a `pull_request` event, this is a merge reference, like as-if already merged (`refs/pull/...`[¹](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request)); this is *not* a branch reference (`refs/heads/...`).

Now when you command Microsoft Github Actions to push with the following instructions:

```
            - name: Push Changes
              uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
              with:
                  github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
                  branch: ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}
```

You're specifically instructing to **not** push any committed changes, but the (unchanged) pull request target branch `${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}`.

---

Now the fix is easy, you may already think so: checkout the correct branch [`with` the `ref` property](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/v3.5.2/README.md?plain=1#L28-L31):

```
        steps:
            - name: Check Out Repository
              uses: actions/checkout@v3
              with:
                ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}
```

---

TLDR; Checkout the correct branch.

Microsoft Github Actions just adds a couple layers of abstractions around `git(1)`. When something unexpected happens, double-check the **real** `git(1)` workflow is clear (e.g. like your local testing), then verify the Microsoft Github Action Workflow uses the correct actions with the correct configuration step by step.

---

Cf. [How to get the current branch within Github Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58033366/367456)

Comment: Thank you, it worked when I wrote it the way you said. That's the part I missed.

Comment: @phoique: You're welcome. It's easy to miss as the cause is in the very beginning but can be validated only after the last step, the pushing. So easy to miss.